# Repeat scroll function while mouse hovering over element

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

is there a way how to repeat a function as long as the cursor is hovering over a specific dom element? I want to perform a scroll operation as long as long as the user is hovering over an arrow with an optional timeout. This task should be fullfillled **without** using jquery!

Here is my current code:

```
public overDown() {
    this.tabList.nativeElement.scrollBy(0, 10);
    const element = this.tabList.nativeElement;
    if(element.offsetHeight + element.scrollTop >= element.scrollHeight) {
      console.log('Bottom Limit');
    }
  }

  public overUp() {
    this.tabList.nativeElement.scrollBy(0, -10);
    const element = this.tabList.nativeElement;
    if(element.scrollTop === 0) {
      console.log('Top Limit');
    }
  }
```

And the HTML

```
<div class="list-arrow-up" (mouseover)="overUp()">▲</div>
  <ul #tabList>
    <li><!--several List items --></span></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="list-arrow-down" (mouseover)="overDown()">▼</div>
```

Comment: You would need to add your scroll via a setInterval() on mouseover and then clear the interval on mouseleave.

Comment: Have your `over....()` functions start a loop and add some `mouseout` events to stop the loop?

Comment: Can you both please provide me with some sample code or a link to a working example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a different aproach.
I would execute a function when hovering over this specific DOM element, that scrolls down to the bottom, lasting x seconds.
And then I would execute another function that stops this scroll down when cursor goes away from this element.
You can improve performance by checking if you are already at the bottom of the page befor executing scroll down.

Comment: Can you please link me a example using such an approach with starting and stopping functions

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you. Change `moveDown` and `moveUp` function based on your requirement. This is javascript code, change this code to angular TypeScript.

HTML

```
<a onmouseover="overDown()" onmouseleave="stopMoveDown = true">Down</a>
<a onmouseover="overUp()" onmouseleave="stopMoveUp = true">Up</a>
```

JavaScript

```
  var stopMoveDown = false;
  var stopMoveUp = false;

  function moveDown() {
     console.log('Move Down');
     if(!stopMoveDown)
        setTimeout(moveDown, 100);
  }

  function moveUp() {
     console.log('Move Up');
     if(!stopMoveUp)
        setTimeout(moveUp, 100);
  }

  function overDown(){
    stopMoveDown = false;
    moveDown();
  }

  function overUp(){
    stopMoveUp = false;
    moveUp();
  }
```

Click here to view demo, open console window and you can see the move up/down in the console window when mouse over Down/Up links.
https://liveweave.com/bFG3OP